# Lebesgue Integral of a sequence

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Take measure space as $\left(X,\mathcal B (X),\mu \right)$ where $\mathcal B (X)$ is Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$ and $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

Show that $\int fd\mu \neq \lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n d\mu$ where $f_n= \frac1n$ and $f=0$

I have shown that $f_n$ is decreasing sequence and converges to $f$ uniformly and $\int fd\mu =0 $ (a.e.) but I cannot identify what is $\int f_n d\mu$

Our definition for positive functions is $\int fd\mu = \sup \{\varphi : 0 \leq \varphi \leq f  \ \ \text{and} \ \  \varphi \ \ \text{is simple} \}$

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the space has infinite measure.

If $\forall n \in \Bbb{N},$you take $\phi_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}1_X$ then $0 \leq \phi_n \leq f$ and

$\int_Xf_n \geq \frac{1}{n}\mu(X)$ by definition.

So the limit is not true.

In a space of finite measure,it is true .

Comment: Won’t there be an uncertainity of infinity divided by infinity when I am taking limit of $\mu (X)/n$?

Comment: No because inf the measure is infinite then it is the fractions is $+\infty$..you do not need to take limits.

Comment: Daily vote limit reached but I agree - one cannot integrate $x\mapsto\frac1x$ over a set of infinite measure, and the problem simply says "$\mu$ is Lebesgue measure," suggesting that the integral would be over $\mathbb R$.